# Typescript class enhancer and static methods

Tags: typescript, next.js

For a NextJS application I would like to create an App (_app.tsx) class enhancer, but I can't get it to work to call the static method of the passed base app class.

```
interface Constructor<T> {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
  prototype: T;
}

class MockNextApp<P={}>{
    props: P;
    static getInitialProps = (ctx: {}) => {foo:"bar"}

    constructor(props: P) {
        this.props = props;
    }
}

function enhanceApp<T extends Constructor<MockNextApp>>(Base: T) {
    return class extends Base{
        static getInitialProps = (ctx: {}) => {
            return Base.getInitialProps();
        }
    }
}
```

Typescript errors with:

```
Property 'getInitialProps' does not exist on type 'T'.
```

You can view the example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Constructor%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20prototype%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MockNextApp%3CP%3D%7B%7D%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20props%3A%20P%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20getInitialProps%20%3D%20(ctx%3A%20%7B%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7Bfoo%3A%22bar%22%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(props%3A%20P)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.props%20%3D%20props%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20enhanceApp%3CT%20extends%20Constructor%3CMockNextApp%3E%3E(Base%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20extends%20Base%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20getInitialProps%20%3D%20(ctx%3A%20%7B%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Base.getInitialProps()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Constructor` will mean that this will be a constructor function that returns `MockNextApp`, but this says nothing about any other static properties `Base` should have.

We can use an inline type that contains both the constructor signature and the extra static property you need in the function :

```
class MockNextApp<P={}>{
    props: P;
    static getInitialProps = (ctx: {}) => ({foo:"bar"}) // I think you mean to return an object literal, without the (), the arrow function actually returns void.

    constructor(props: P) {
        this.props = props;
    }
}

function enhanceApp<T extends {
    new(...args: any[]): MockNextApp;
    getInitialProps(): { foo: string }
}>(Base: T) {
    return class extends Base{
        static getInitialProps = (ctx: {}) => {
            return Base.getInitialProps();
        }
    }
}
```